# Does the Warforged's Heavy Plating AC calculation have a minimum required Strength score?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, armor, racial-traits, warforged

I want to play a warforged fighter/wizard, and I was wondering because of the confusing armor explanation for warforged.

Do I have to have a strength of 15 or 13 for the Heavy Plating, since heavy armor has a required strength?

Comment: Yes for the first one, but for the second one, am I supposed to have a 13 in strength because of heavy armor, or do I not have to have that because its my racial ability?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Are you using the current version of the warforged from the Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron (the same version that appears in [this Eberron Races UA](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.1.pdf))?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Entering Heavy Plating Mode does not have a required minimum Strength score

The [Warforged's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged) Integrated Protection features states:

> [...] You can alter your body to enter different defensive modes; each time you finish a long rest, choose one mode to adopt from the Integrated Protection table, **provided you meet the mode's prerequisite**...

Each mode's prerequisites are listed in the table provided and the only prerequisites for entering Heavy Plating Mode are:

> Heavy armor proficiency

This means that this is the *only* prerequisite, nothing else. As a result, **there is no strength requirement for activating Heavy Plating Mode**